# Jenkins : Send email to different recipients

Tags: jenkins, hudson, email-ext

I want to send email notifications to different recipients when my tests fail in different folders.
Is this possible by using the Email-ext Jenkins plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an environment variable for the recipient list
Then use Conditional Step plugin to determine where was the failure. Inside the Conditional step, use "Inject Environment Variables" plugin to set the mailing list on each case.

Then use this environment var at the Recipient List

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's a comma separated recipient list:
[image]

Comment: I want to send email to different recipients when tests of one folder fail and to different recipients when tests fail of another folder.

Comment: Yes, that's also supported. Can make a screenshot to the answer if you need.

Comment: @Fayzan look again :)

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. I know about these options

Comment: I got it, forgot that https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin is not the default plugin. With that you can parse the output within the executed log and add email notifications depending on what you want. Sure you will need to parse it programmatically on your own. One probnlem is Email-ext is post-build action and we need it to be as a build action. Then you will need https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Any+Build+Step+Plugin also.